# Insufficient Privileges: plone.app.multilingual [1.x] - Translate an Archetype content

Tags: python, plone, multilingual

I got a really strange behaviour, if I want to translate an Archetype contenttype (for example `Folder`) with plone.app.multilingual.

Error msg:

```
Insufficient Privileges

You do not have sufficient privileges to view this page. If you believe you are 
receiving this message in error, contact the site administration.
```

My environment:

- Plone = 4.3.2
- plone.app.multilingual = 1.2.1
- plone.multilingual = 1.2.1
- plone.multilingualbehavior = 1.2
- archetypes.multilingual = 1.2
- And about 40 Plone Addon's (**which makes this really complex**)

My use case:

- Two languages are configured EN and DE
- Plone's simple_publication_workflow is configured.
- All items are in the private state. (LanguageRoot folders are in private state too)

I can reproduce this problem by first creating a content (Folder) in the english part of the site. The content is private, since this is the default state for new content.

Then I try to translate the content into german by clicking on the Translate menu -> `create German`. Done... the error `Insufficient Privileges` appears.

If I install a vanilla Plone 4.3.2 and plone.app.multilingial without my huge bunch of addons everything works fine. I pretty sure there's a problem with one of the addons but I need to understand what leads to this problem. It doesn't matters, which addon breaks the site.

Further...

Since it's a permission problem I first tried it to publish everything and then translate the content into German. This worked well!

Well, next step was debugging into plone.app.multilingual. I ended up in the [add.py AddTraverser](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.multilingual/blob/1.x/src/plone/app/multilingual/browser/add.py#L30)

The problem appears on the [redirect on line 37](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.multilingual/blob/1.x/src/plone/app/multilingual/browser/add.py#L37) If one part of the url is not public accessible (Anonymous??) the error happens.

imho it's strange that the implementation of the DX part and AT part is different.

I changed the AT part implementation to:

```python
self.context.REQUEST.set('type', name)
view = queryMultiAdapter((self.context, self.context.REQUEST),
                             name="add_at_translation")
return view.__of__(self.context)
```

instead of:

```python
baseUrl = self.context.absolute_url()
url = '%s/@@add_at_translation?type=%s' % (baseUrl, name)
return self.request.response.redirect(url)
```

**This totally fixed my case. And all plone.app.multilingual tests are still working.**

But I cannot explain why?
And why it doesn't work without the customization?

Any hint is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Why your fix works, could be related to that the user may not be authenticated during traverse. This is similar to, why user may not be authenticated during browser views' `__init__`.

That might be a bug, and a pull request with your fix, and a test that proves your point by failing without it, would be preferred.

You should be able to get a better error message by removing Unauthorized from filtered errors in `/Plone/error_log` (via ZMI). I'm not sure, how `absolute_url` can raise Unauthorized in any condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already removed `Unauthorized` from `error_log` and the error message (`Incorrect username or password` and nearly no tracback) was confusing, until I saw the code snipped I posted in the question. I need to get my environment up again and try to reproduce the "bug". I'll check the answer a soon I'm sure this resolves the problem.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping that the traceback for Unauthorized would reveal the real issue. Do you remember, did the redirection to ``@@add_at_translation`` really happen before the error? One possible issue is that response.redirect() does not do immediate redirect and returns just a string, which may up breaking the traverse somehow with your set of add-ons.

Comment: Imho, you were both right :), but more importantly this discussion helped a lot in finally figuring this out.  After debugging how the traversal code handles the empty string value returned from the adapter I thought the solution must be instantiating the view directly (instead or the redirection), but strangely things were working on a published folder. Luckily you already provided a working implementation plus the necessary hints to get to the end… :)

In any case, https://github.com/plone/plone.app.multilingual/pull/351 contains the fix and some more info.